# Using a plane to cut Volume Data X3D

Tags: javascript, x3d, x3dom

So I'm currently trying to take the example on this site https://examples.x3dom.org/example/RadarVolumeStyle/ and replicate it in notepad to then use it to my own ends. I pretty much have everything working but for some reason the colors for the volume don't seem to render properly and the sliders aren't working. I've looked at the code and can't really figure out anything that's wrong with it so I'm wondering how to get the slider working to cut the Volume like it does on the link. The source code I have is as follows:

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge"></meta>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="x3dom-1.7.2/x3dom.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="x3dom-1.7.2/x3dom-full.js"></script>
  </head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function start() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
                var s = (evt.target.response || evt.target.responseText).split("\n");
                var heights = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                    var s2 = s[i].split(",");
                    for(var j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                        heights += s2[j]/15.0 + " ";
                }
                var elem = document.getElementById("dem_elevation_grid");
                elem.setAttribute("height", heights);
                elem.setAttribute("xDimension", 256);
                elem.setAttribute("zDimension", 256);
                elem.setAttribute("xSpacing", 0.0156863);
                elem.setAttribute("zSpacing", 0.0156863);
            });

            xhr.open('GET', 'data/dem.csv', true);
            xhr.send(null);

            var w = document.getElementById("x3d").getAttribute("width");
            var h = document.getElementById("x3d").getAttribute("height");

            document.getElementById("deptex").setAttribute("dimensions", w.substring(0, w.length-2) + " " + h.substring(0, h.length-2) + " 4");

            document.getElementById("iso").oninput = (function() {
                document.getElementById("vs").setAttribute("isoSurfaceCutoffValue", this.value);
            });

            document.getElementById("mcp").oninput = (function() {
                document.getElementById("cut_plane_translation").setAttribute("translation", "0.0 0.0 " + 2.0*(this.value - 0.5));
                document.getElementById("vs").setAttribute("xSectionPosition", this.value);
            });
    }
  </script>

  <body style="background:white" onload="start();">
    <div id="x3d_container" style="position:relative;">
        <X3D id="x3d" xmlns='http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-namespace'
            showStat='false' showLog='false' width='800px' height='600px'>
            <Scene>
                <Background DEF="bg" transparency ='0.0' skyColor='0.9 0.9 1.0'></Background>
                <Viewpoint DEF="vp" description='Default' orientation="1 0 0 -0.4" position="0 2.535 6" zNear='0.1' zFar='100.0' fieldOfView="0.5"></Viewpoint>
                <navigationInfo type='turntable' typeParams="0 0 -0.4 1.57" id="navType"></navigationInfo>
                <Group>
                    <Group DEF="cut">
                        <SphereSensor id="SPHSENSOR" DEF='SPHSENSOR' autoOffset='true' description='click and drag to rotate'></SphereSensor>
                        <Transform rotation="0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0">
                            <Transform DEF="SPHROT" id="cut_plane_rotation">
                                <Transform DEF="SPHTRANS" id="cut_plane_translation" translation="0.0 0.0 0.0">
                                    <Shape DEF="cut_plane">
                                        <Appearance>
                                            <BlendMode></BlendMode>
                                            <Material id="x3hprycjk" emissiveColor='0.2 0.2 0.2'></Material>
                                        </Appearance>
                                        <IndexedLineSet onmouseover='document.getElementById("x3hprycjk").setAttribute("emissiveColor", "0.1 0.1 0.9");'  onmouseout='document.getElementById("x3hprycjk").setAttribute("emissiveColor", "0.2 0.2 0.2");' coordIndex='0 1 2 3 0 -1'>
                                            <Coordinate DEF='TurnPoints_2' point='-1 -1 0 1 -1 0 1 1 0 -1 1 0'></Coordinate>
                                        </IndexedLineSet>
                                    </Shape>
                                    <Transform rotation="0 0 1 1.57"><Shape use="cut_plane"></Transform>
                                    <Transform rotation="0 0 1 3.142"><Shape use="cut_plane"></Transform>
                                    <Transform rotation="0 0 1 -1.57"><Shape use="cut_plane"></Transform>
                                </Transform>
                            </Transform>
                        </Transform>
                        <ROUTE fromField='rotation_changed' fromNode='SPHSENSOR' toField='set_rotation' toNode='SPHROT'></ROUTE>
                    </Group>

                    <Group DEF="dem">
                        <Transform translation='-2.0 -1.0 -2.0'>
                            <shape>
                                <appearance sortType="opaque">
                                    <ImageTexture url='data/dem.jpg'></ImageTexture>
                                </appearance>
                                <ElevationGrid id="dem_elevation_grid" height='0 0 0 0' creaseAngle='0.8' xDimension='2' zDimension='2' xSpacing='4.0' zSpacing='4.0'></ElevationGrid>
                            </shape>
                        </Transform>
                    </Group>

                    <VolumeData dimensions='2.0 2.0 2.0'>
                        <ImageTextureAtlas id="ita" containerField="voxels" url="data/kansai_pawr_20120726175907.png" numberOfSlices="64" slicesOverX="8" slicesOverY="8">
                        </ImageTextureAtlas>
                        <RadarVolumeStyle id="vs" DEF="VOLREN3D" isoSurfaceCutoffValue="0.3" transparency="1.0" intensityLimits="0.1 0.6" renderMode="2" xSectionPosition="0.5">
                            <ImageTexture containerField='transferFunction' url='data/rainbow.png'></ImageTexture>
                            <RenderedTexture id="deptex" containerField='depthTexture' update="always" dimensions="800 600 4" depthMap="true">
                                <Viewpoint USE="vp"></Viewpoint>
                                <Background USE="bg"></Background>
                                <Transform>
                                    <group USE="cut"></group>
                                    <group USE="dem"></group>
                                </Transform>
                            </RenderedTexture>
                        </RadarVolumeStyle>
                    </VolumeData>
                    <ROUTE fromField='rotation_changed' fromNode='SPHSENSOR' toField='xSectionOrientation' toNode='VOLREN3D'></ROUTE>
                </Group>
            </Scene>
        </X3D>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;font-family:verdana; margin-left: 10px">
        <p>Threshold:</p>
        <input id="iso" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" ></input>

        <p>Move Plane:</p>
        <input id="mcp" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" ></input>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:left; float:left; font-family:verdana; font-size: 12px">This achievement is part of “research and development of next-generation Doppler radar technology” contract research from National<br/> Institute of Information and Communications Technology Japan. (c) 2015 Toshiba Corporation</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code and the resulting page looks good - colours are as in the example, and both sliders do what they are supposed to do. So my guess is that there is something wrong the other files that are used. Are kansai_pawr_20120726175907.png and rainbow.png there, and in the right place?

UPDATE: I think I have just encountered a similar problem, caused by different versions of x3dom-full.js. Could you try your example using the same x3dom-full.js file that is used in https://examples.x3dom.org/example/RadarVolumeStyle/? It is about 5 MB, whereas x3dom-full.js from the 1.7.2 distribution is only 1,2 MB.